# Best way to represent data

Tags: time-series, data-visualization, dataset, presentation

What is the best way to represent the following data graphically? Can I use a histogram

```
Year    Output per Person       Capital Employed
2010    16.3 units/annum        £40,000 p.p
2011    15.1 units/annum        £38,000 p.p
2012    14.4 units /annum       £35,000 p.p
2013    11.7 units per annum    £33,000 p.p
2014    10.8 units per annum    £30,000 p.p
```

Comment: You have three variables (year, output, capital).  Are you interested in the relationship between output and capital, or is it their individual behaviour over time you care about -- or something else? What *aspects* of the information matter for you? (Is this for some subject or is it a real issue you face?)

Comment: @Glen_b I'm interested in the relationship between output and the capital? I want to show that when capital employed is decreased, output also decreased

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see two main alternatives, the scatterplot (see Stephan's post, or a slightly different version below which is sometimes worth trying with time series), and superimposed time series (see the second plot below), though there are a number of other possibilities.

However, beware of interpreting the [appearance of correlation as meaningful](http://www.tylervigen.com/). Specifically, since both your quantities are both "per person, per annum", you have a classical situation where you expect [*spurious correlation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_correlation_of_ratios) in the original sense of the term.

[image]

[image]

Comment: One comment: double-axis plots are often discouraged and may be easily misleading so should be used with caution.

Comment: @Tim I agree they *can* be misleading, which is why the axes were color-coded to match the lines -- looking at it, do you really think this one is misleading?

Comment: No I don't :) I'm just saying it is worth mentioning that this particular kind of plot should be used with caution.

Comment: @Tim - It'd be helpful to hear in what way and in what circumstances they can mislead.

Answer (score 6):

Probably best to do a simple scatterplot. Using R:

```
foo <- data.frame(year=2010:2014,output=c(16.3,15.1,14.4,11.7,10.8),
  capital=c(40,38,35,33,30)*1000)
with(foo,plot(capital,output,xlab="Capital Employed",ylab="Output per Person",pch=19))
```

[image: scatterplot]

Or also plot the years:

```
with(foo,plot(capital,output,xlab="Capital Employed",ylab="Output per Person",pch=NA))
with(foo,text(capital,output,year))
```

[image: scatterplot with years]

However, note that *both* capital and output decline over time. So either output is driven by capital... or both are independently driven by some time-dependent trend (or something in between). Be careful when interpreting correlations, especially over time.